# How to use @FindBy for driver.findElements(By.xpath(<Locator String>)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-factory

i am trying to use @FindBy to initialize all the page elements.
I understand @FindBy can be used to initialize a single webelement, but can it be used to initialize a list of webelements?
I am trying to incorporate driver.findElements(By.xpath() (which will return a list of webelements) way in @FindBy.
how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use @FindBy to find multiple elements as well. You just need to change type of element variable. For Example ,

@FindBy("your locator")
List elementName;

init method of page factory will initialize this element same as it initialize for single webelement.

Comment: would be better if using `List<WebElement>` instead of raw type `List`